# Auto grow table-cell element by content

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I'm trying to make a table with the `display:table-cell` and `display:table` css properties. It looks like this:

[image: Table example]

My problem is that the orange table cell needs to be just as big as its inner content. Sometimes the green boxes are 100px and sometimes they are 200px. The `.left` should auto-grow. I would like a CSS solution for this problem. Is that possible?

It should look like this:

[image: Should be like this]

[Here's the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KeesCBakker/q8e3j/). And here's the code:

**Html:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left">
        <div class="tree">A
            <br/>- B
            <br/>- C
            <br/>
        </div>
        <div class="filter">F
            <br/>F2
            <br/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">A A A
        <br/>B B B
        <br/>C C C
        <br/>
    </div>
    <div class="right">S
        <br/>S2
        <br/>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div {
    margin:2px;
    padding:2px;
}
.wrapper {
    width:700px;
    border:solid 1px red;
    display:table;
    table-layout:fixed;
}
.right {
    display:table-cell;
    border:solid 1px blue;
    width:100px;
}
.left {
    display:table-cell;
    border:dashed 1px orange;
}
.content {
    display:table-cell;
}
.tree, .filter {
    display:block;
    width:100px;
    border:solid 1px green;
}
```

The `.left` doesn't play nice :(

Comment: What is wrong with the `<table>` element?

Comment: The HTML Table still works okay. My problem has to do with CSS ;-)

Answer (score 1):

### Edit2

Place width: 100px on your left class and remove `table-layout:fixed;` from wrapper class

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/q8e3j/11/)**

### EDIT

In your markup remove whitespaces in .left class when it is empty like so:

```
<div class="left"></div> or also like:

<div class="left"><!-- some comment is also ok--></div>
```

This is necessary because otherwise the :empty selector won't consider this element empty.

In css add this:

```
.left:empty
{
    display:none;
}
```

new **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/q8e3j/10/)**

---

How about wrapping the content of your .left class within another div - like so:

```
<div class="left">
   <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Then, if you like, you could remove the border if .inner has no content - like so:

```
.inner:empty
{
    border:none;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/q8e3j/7/)**

Comment: It is not yet what I need. I've added a picture on how it should look like. The left cell should grow only as big as its content. The content cell should auto grow.

Comment: The second table looks good now! But the first still does not 'auto-grow' to the content of the table.

Comment: Nice, but the problem is that I don't know how big the content in `.left` is going to get. Sometimes it is 100px, sometimes 150px.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the div containing the left class in your HTML to a span

```
<span class="left">
    <!-- no content, should not be displayed !-->
</span>
```

Then change your CSS changing your display from table-cell to inline-block

```
.left {
display:inline-block;
border:dashed 1px orange;
}
```

You could also try this...
[FIDDLE Again](http://jsfiddle.net/q8e3j/15/)

Comment: When I do that, I end up with this picture: http://screencast.com/t/Q3Ds3bg5. The left cell is still present, but the contentpart should replace it. The content should auto grow.

Comment: Added an image on how it should like.

Comment: that's because it is not necessary to wrap green div in dashed orange

Comment: @EL the borders are not important for me. Do you have a solution without the wrapping?

Comment: @TateReynolds 2nd table is okay, the 1st table is still bigger than the content. It should auto-grow.

Comment: @KeesC.Bakker Edited again... You could always set the width to auto; assuming you want that table layout type look.

Comment: @Kees C. Bakker yeah, probably set it as `inline-block` too